# React/Webpack issue when trying to import style sheets

Tags: reactjs, webpack

so i have a few styles i need to bring in to get a carousel working

```
// general styles
import 'style!css!react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/main.css';

// carousel styles
import 'style!css!react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.css';
```

the trouble is i get the following error and being new to webpack/react i have little idea, i can only assume that it is down to a webpack config or a module that i need to handle css but other than that i am at a loss.

```
./~/css-loader!./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":5,"extract":true,"remove":true}!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/less-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.css
...
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

So here is my webpack config

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './js/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js',
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style!css!postcss!less!', 'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)\w*/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 5 versions']})
    ];
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'js', 'fw', 'lib')
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css', {allChunks: true}),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.bundle.js'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'fortafy-website',
      description: 'website for fortafy technologies',
      username: 'Samuel.Blackwell',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      template: 'index.html_vm',
      favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',
      hash: false
    })
  ]
};
```

this is the component i am trying to get to work : http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/

Comment: Since you're already performing the CSS transformations in your webpack config, what happens if you just import the style without the added injected loader syntax (i.e. `import 'responsive-carousel/lib/styles/main.css'`);

Comment: when i do that i get no styles applied but i do see all the unstyled components of the carousel

Comment: And I assume the generated `bundle.css` is empty in that case? At any rate, feel free to have a peek here: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate, https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate/blob/master/src/Bootstrap.jsx#L10

Comment: embarassingly i am not sure how to locate that, doing a search for where that ended up.....completely green with webpack so of course everything is currently black magic.

Comment: It sounds like you might be building webpack in `dev`, which actually *doesn't* generate any files (they are only kept in memory), however if you build for production `webpack -p` it should generate the files for your distribution, which you've configured to go to `./build`. Might be worth inspecting to output to see if the ExtactPlugin is doing it's job

Comment: it is doing its job, turns out i can see carousel styles in there :O

Comment: carousel__carousel___3KBns .carousel__slide___33L2B iframe{display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - 80px);margin:0 40px 40px;border:0}.carousel__carousel___3KBns .carousel__slide___33L2B .carousel__legend___2_S-o{transition:all .5s ease-in- ;position:absolute;bottom:40px;left:50%;margin-left:-45%;width:90%;border-radius:10px;background:#000;color:#fff;padding:10px;font-size:12px;text-align:center;opacity:.25;transition:opacity .35s 

output looks like this

Comment: Oddly named classes, but other than that, looks valid. Might be worth popping over the dev console (F12), and using the DOM inspector to see why, although the styles are present, are not being applied to your elements.

Comment: indeed they are not. none of the classes are being applied, very confusing :O

Comment: Hm, interesting. If you feel like slapping together a plunkr, or codepen, where I could reproduce, I'd be happy to take a peek.

Comment: I will comment tomorrow when i get some time, thanks for your time.